# Complex regex pattern with specific length

Tags: regex

Maybe I am not phrasing this correctly, but I couldn't find anything helpful, so here I am. I need to match numbers and dashes with exact length of 10 symbols. Regex would look like this:

```
/[0-9-]{10}/g
```

The catch is that this would match '8888888888' and '----------' respectively and I want to avoid that. My output should resemble a number, thus I want to match if both '-' and 'digit' are present.It should look something like '555-45-217', '12-34-5412', '1-2-3-45-6. This is what I have so far:

```
([0-9]+-[0-9]+(-[0-9]+)*){10}
```

But this doesn't work. {} just gives error, when following (). So my question is how can I achieve such goal? How to match only if both  conditions (rules inside and proper amount of symbols) are present.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can use

```
^(?=[0-9-]{10}$)\d+(?:-\d+)+$
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/tLQ3fZ/1)

**Details**:

- `^` - start of string
- `(?=[0-9-]{10}$)` - the string should only consist of 10 chars, either digits or `-`
- `\d+` - 1 or more digits
- `(?:-\d+)+` - 1 or more sequences of `-` followed with 1+ digits
- `$` - end of string.

Comment: Hello, Wiktor. Thanks for the response. Now let me see if I get this correctly - within the first set of () you use positive lookahead to specify the length and then you setup the rules for the multiple '-num' sections. Now I am trying to modify it in such a way that it matches with '+' at start - '+555-12-345'. Lastly I need to find matches in long string so I need my end delimiter to look something like '(?=\s|%)'. Maybe this last lookahead is not working, because the previous lookahead specifies only 10 symbols lenght? idk. Here is my try: \+(?=[0-9-]{10}$)\d+(?:-\d+)+(?=\s|$)

Comment: An optional `+` and the word boundaries to the rescue: [`\+?(?=[0-9-]{10}\b)\d+(?:-\d+)+\b`](https://regex101.com/r/tLQ3fZ/2).